# How update ProgressBar as custom ListActivity item

Tags: android

I try to do a view to show multiple files download.
ProgressDialog is great to showing single file download info, but i think it can't be used as element of ListView or somehow set for multiple files indication (or can it?)

So i implement own adapter as shown in some guides like [this](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/), and it works ok, i can add Download Items (TextView with name + ProgressBar with max set to file size), but how update ProgressBar at some list item?

**If this is a bad practice, which way is best to display multiple files download progress?**

**download_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/download_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/download_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/download_label" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Download class**

```
public class Download 
{
  public String name;
  public int size;

  public Download(String name, int size)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = size;
  }
}
```

**DownloadAdapter class**

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class DownloadsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Download>
 {
   private int layoutResourceId;
   public DownloadsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId)
   {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    this.layoutResourceId = textViewResourceId;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {
     DownloadHolder downloadHolder = null;
         if(convertView == null)
         {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) super.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            downloadHolder = new DownloadHolder();
            downloadHolder.progressBar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.download_bar);
            downloadHolder.label = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.download_label);
            Log.i("INFO", "HOLDER SET");
            convertView.setTag(downloadHolder);
         }
         else
         {
            downloadHolder = (DownloadHolder)convertView.getTag();
         }

        Download download = super.getItem(position);
        downloadHolder.label.setText(download.name);
        downloadHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        downloadHolder.progressBar.setMax(download.size);
        return convertView;
    }

public static class DownloadHolder
{
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView label;
}

   }
```

**DownloadView class**

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DownloadsView extends ListActivity
{
   public static DownloadsAdapter DOWNLOADS = null;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      DOWNLOADS = new DownloadsAdapter(this, R.layout.download_item);
      setListAdapter(DOWNLOADS);
      //TEST
      /*
      DownloadsView.addDownload("Lol", 232);
      DownloadsView.addDownload("fsfs", 123);
     */ 
 }

    public static void addDownload(String name, int size)
    {   
      DOWNLOADS.add(new Download(name, size));
    }  
}
```

Comment: I did something like this a month ago... I'll post code tomorrow when i get to the office. Remind me :) I think it comes in a form of a fully-contained dialog so it's kinda plug and playable :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so here goes...

```
package com.skype.transfer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.skype.api.Transfer;
import com.skype.ref.R;

/*****
 * This class is in charge of displaying ongoing transfers in a ListView
 * <p>
 * The methods of relevance are {@link #getItem()}, {@link #getCount()} and
 * {@link #getView()}.
 * 
 * @author Aleksandar Milenkovic
 */
public class TransferArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Transfer>
{
    private ArrayList<Transfer> values      = null;
    private Vector<Boolean>     selectedStates;
    private Context             context;

    private ImageView           transferType;
    private TextView            filename;
    private ProgressBar         progress;
    private TextView            details;

    private static final String ASSETS_DIR  = "images/";
    private static final String LOGTAG      = "TransferArrayAdapter";

    /**
     * The default constructor which is invoked to create the current transfers'
     * array adapter
     * 
     * @param context
     *            the application context
     * @param textViewResourceId
     *            The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use
     *            when instantiating views.
     * @param objects
     *            the backing array populated by Buddy objects to be displayed.
     * @see {@link ArrayAdapter}<T>
     */
    public TransferArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Transfer> objects)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = objects;
        //      selectedStates = new Vector<Boolean>();
        //      clearSelectedState();
    }

    /**
     * How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.
     * 
     * @return the trimmed size of the backing array.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        this.values.trimToSize();
        return this.values.size();
    }

    /**
     * Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data set.
     * 
     * @param index
     *            Position of the item whose data we want within the adapter's
     *            data set.
     * @return the Transfer item at the indicated position in the backing array
     */
    @Override
    public Transfer getItem(int index)
    {
        if (index <= getCount())    //IndexOutOfBoundsException fix
            return this.values.get(index);
        return this.values.get(values.size());
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to generate views to be used in the ListView. This
     * the method that defines how data will look and be represented throughout
     * the UI.
     * 
     * @param position
     *            The position of the item that is being placed / The position
     *            of the item within the adapter's data set of the item whose
     *            view we want.
     *            <p>
     * @param convertView
     *            The old view to reuse, if possible. Note: You should check
     *            that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before
     *            using. If it is not possible to convert this view to display
     *            the correct data, this method can create a new view.
     *            Heterogeneous lists can specify their number of view types, so
     *            that this View is always of the right type (see
     *            getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int))
     *            <p>
     * @param parent
     *            The parent that this view will eventually be attached to
     * @return the view that defines how this Buddy object is represented in the
     *         ListView / A View corresponding to the data at the specified
     *         position.
     * 
     * @see {@link BaseAdapter#getView(int, View, ViewGroup)}
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transfer_item, parent, false);
            //          row.setTag(convertView);
        }

        Transfer file = getItem(position);
        //      Log.d(LOGTAG, "getView(): file at position "+position+"= "+file);
        if (file == null) return row;

        transferType = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.transfer_type);
        filename = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.transfer_filename);
        progress = (ProgressBar) row.findViewById(R.id.transfer_progress);
        details = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.transfer_details);

        //filename, progress, details
        filename.setText(FileUtils.getFilenameFor(file));
        progress.setProgress(FileUtils.getProgressFor(file));

        switch (FileUtils.getStatusFor(file))
        {
            case PAUSED:
                details.setText("Paused");
                break;

            case WAITING_FOR_ACCEPT:
                details.setText("Waiting...");
                break;

            case CANCELLED:
            case CANCELLED_BY_REMOTE:
                details.setText("Canceled");
                break;

            default:
                details.setText(FileUtils.getTransferInfo(file));
                break;
        }

        //image stuff
        String imgFilePath = ASSETS_DIR;
        switch (FileUtils.getTransferTypeFor(file))
        {
            case INCOMING:
                imgFilePath += "incoming_file.png";
                break;

            case OUTGOING:
                imgFilePath += "outcoming_file.png";
                break;
        }

        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.context.getResources().getAssets().open(imgFilePath));
            transferType.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(LOGTAG + "Exception", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error while setting " + FileUtils.getFilenameFor(file) + " type icon to: " + imgFilePath);
        }

        return row;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to clear all selection states on the view's children.
     */
    public void clearSelectedState()
    {
        selectedStates.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i <= getCount(); i++)
        {
            selectedStates.add(Boolean.valueOf(false));
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to make a certain position 'selected'.
     * <p>
     * After setting selection, notifyDataSetChanged() will be called.
     * 
     * @param position
     *            the position to select
     */
    public void setSelectedState(int position)
    {
        //clear selected state vector
        clearSelectedState();
        //set selected position
        selectedStates.set(position, Boolean.valueOf(true));
        //refresh adapter to redraw focus
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Method to use to update a Transfer's UI
     * 
     * @param file
     *            file to display
     * @param overRelay
     *            is the transfer going over a relay
     */
    public void updateTransfer(Transfer file, boolean overRelay)
    {
        //TODO: use overRelay to indicate slower transfer

        int index = values.indexOf(file);

        if (index < 0)
        {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return;
        }

        getView(index, null, null).postInvalidate();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

FileUtils will not be compatible with your files so I will leave it's implementation to you. But it maps transfers to contacts that sent them. It's just a utility hashmap helper class :)

Heres the XML

incoming_file.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/incoming_files_subtitle1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/incoming_file" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/incoming_files_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/incoming_files_subtitle1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/incoming_files_subtitle2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/incoming_files_detail"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/saved_at" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/incoming_files_path"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/incoming_files_subtitle2"
        android:inputType="textUri" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/incoming_files_browse"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/incoming_files_path"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/incoming_files_path"
        android:text="@string/browse" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/incoming_files_accept"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/accept" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/incoming_files_cancel"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

transfer_dialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/transfer_button_holder"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_transfer_incoming"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/incoming"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_transfer_outgoing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/outgoing"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_transfer_finished"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/finished"/>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_transfer_all"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/view_all"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/transfer_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="650dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_below="@+id/transfer_button_holder"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selector_list" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

transfer_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/transfer_type"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/transfer_filename"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/transfer_type"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/empty_string" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/transfer_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/transfer_filename"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/transfer_type"
        android:max="100" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/transfer_details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/transfer_progress"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/transfer_type"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/empty_string" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Transfer dialog code, will need adaptation:

```
private void showTransfersDialog()
    {
        transferDialog = new Dialog(context);
        transferDialog.setContentView(R.layout.transfer_dialog);

        transferDialog.setTitle(R.string.transfer_manager);
        transferDialog.setCancelable(true);

        //set up buttons
        Button btnQuit = (Button) transferDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        Button btnShowIncoming = (Button) transferDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_transfer_incoming);
        Button btnShowOutgoing = (Button) transferDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_transfer_outgoing);
        Button btnShowFinished = (Button) transferDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_transfer_finished);
        Button btnShowAll = (Button) transferDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_transfer_all);

        transferList = (ListView) transferDialog.findViewById(R.id.transfer_list);
        registerForContextMenu(transferList);
        transferList.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                showTransferFileDialog(transferAdapter.getItem(position));
            }
        });
        transferAdapter = new TransferArrayAdapter(SkypeKitVideoDemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                FileUtils.getAllTransfersAsList());

        Log.d(LOGTAG, "transferAdapter = " + transferAdapter);

        Log.d(LOGTAG, "setting adapter to transfers = " + transferList);
        transferList.setAdapter(transferAdapter);

        btnQuit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                transferDialog.dismiss();
                transferDialog = null;
                transferList = null;
            }
        });

        btnShowAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                transferAdapter = new TransferArrayAdapter(SkypeKitVideoDemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FileUtils
                        .getAllTransfersAsList());
                transferList.setAdapter(transferAdapter);
            }
        });

        btnShowIncoming.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                transferAdapter = new TransferArrayAdapter(SkypeKitVideoDemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FileUtils
                        .getAllTransfersOfTypeAsList(Transfer.Type.INCOMING));
                transferList.setAdapter(transferAdapter);
            }
        });

        btnShowOutgoing.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                transferAdapter = new TransferArrayAdapter(SkypeKitVideoDemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FileUtils
                        .getAllTransfersOfTypeAsList(Transfer.Type.OUTGOING));
                transferList.setAdapter(transferAdapter);
            }
        });

        btnShowFinished.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                transferAdapter = new TransferArrayAdapter(SkypeKitVideoDemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FileUtils
                        .getAllFinishedTransfers());
                transferList.setAdapter(transferAdapter);
            }
        });

        //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
        transferDialog.show();

        return;
    }
```

Incoming file dialog:

```
private void showIncomingFileDialog(final Conversation convo, final Transfer[] transfers, final int index)
    {
        incomingFileDialog = new Dialog(context);
        incomingFileDialog.setContentView(R.layout.incoming_file);

        if (index >= transfers.length) return;  //sanity check

        String sender = transfers[index].getPartnerHandle();
        String filename = transfers[index].getFileName();

        incomingFileDialog.setTitle("INCOMING FILES(" + (index + 1) + " / " + transfers.length + ") FROM " + sender);
        incomingFileDialog.setCancelable(false);

        //set up controls
        TextView detail = (TextView) incomingFileDialog.findViewById(R.id.incoming_files_detail);
        final EditText pathToFile = (EditText) incomingFileDialog.findViewById(R.id.incoming_files_path);
        Button btnBrowse = (Button) incomingFileDialog.findViewById(R.id.incoming_files_browse);
        Button btnAccept = (Button) incomingFileDialog.findViewById(R.id.incoming_files_accept);
        Button btnCancel = (Button) incomingFileDialog.findViewById(R.id.incoming_files_cancel);
        pathToFile.setText(savingPath + filename);

        detail.setText(filename + "\t- " + FileUtils.getFilesizeFrom(transfers[index]));

        btnAccept.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                float size = Float.parseFloat(transfers[index].getFileSize());

                if (size < getAvailableFreeSpace())
                {
                    transfers[index].accept(pathToFile.getText().toString());
                    FileUtils.addTransferFrom(convo, transfers[index]);
                } else
                    showFileTooBigDialog(convo, transfers[index], pathToFile.getText().toString());

                if (index == transfers.length - 1)
                {
                    incomingFileDialog.dismiss();
                } else
                {
                    incomingFileDialog.dismiss();
                    showIncomingFileDialog(convo, transfers, index + 1);
                }

            }
        });

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                transfers[index].cancel();
                if (index == transfers.length - 1)
                {
                    incomingFileDialog.dismiss();
                } else
                {
                    incomingFileDialog.dismiss();
                    showIncomingFileDialog(convo, transfers, index + 1);
                }

            }
        });

        btnBrowse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                showFolderPicker(convo, transfers, index);
                incomingFileDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
        incomingFileDialog.show();

        return;
    }
```

These rely on FileUtils but with some effort you can swap Conversation out for a String and Transfer out for a file or some sort of wrapper :)

Comment: Couldn't post FileUtils, it says "body is limited to 30,000 chars I entered 42768" ...

Comment: Well it's ok, but there is a piece of code about updating ProgressBar (in your code it's called "progress") in list element?

Comment: I had a callback availabile, you will have to keep rescheduling the update task (use Executor or TimerTask) to call updateProgress()... i'll post the FileUtils.getProgressFor() method tomorrow. Or not if you call notifyDataSetChanged() after getProgressFor().

Answer (score 1):

You can not update just an item in a `ListView` in `Android`. You should just update the data that the `Adapter` is displaying and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter`.

Comment: But then i need put RelativeLayout, ProgressBar And TextView in Download class? And arrange them as download_item.xml program way?

Comment: your Download.class should also have a member `int currentProgress` and you'll use that to display the `ProgressBar` progress.